# VBScript: Get type of registry value, and delete/create a registry value, *without* using WMI

Tags: vbscript, registry, wmi

I need to create a script that *does not* rely on WMI, to perform the following actions:

1. Check if a registry value exist, and that it has the required type
2. If the registry value exist but of a wrong type, delete it
3. If the registry value does not exist, or was deleted in step #2, create it with a certain type
4. If the registry value exist *and* of the correct type, ensure that its value is correct

Nearly all Registry manipulation VBScript code snippets I found on the Internet relies on WMI. For certain reasons, this is not acceptable.

Do you have any recommendation on how to manipulate the Registry without relying on WMI?

Comment: Parse the contents of a `REG` file that was generated from `REG.EXE /EXPORT` command line.

Comment: @Jay thanks! If you'd write your comment as an answer, I'll gladly check it for you...

Answer (score 0):

VBScript/JScript from *Windows Scripting Host* (WSH) do have registry functions from `WScript.Shell` object, but they are limited to read, write, and delete key/value. There's no function to retrieve the existence of a registry key or value except by reading it and check the result. Function for retrieving a registry value type is also not present.

Other method of accessing the registry except from WMI object is to use the packaged `REG.EXE` command line tool via `WScript.Shell.Exec` function. This is done by using `QUERY`, `ADD`, `DELETE`, `IMPORT`, or `EXPORT` command parameter. Run `REG.EXE` to display the usage summary, or `REG.EXE QUERY /?`, `REG.EXE EXPORT /?`, etc. to display the command usage details.

The output of `QUERY` command would display the value data and its type, if it exists. The `EXPORT` command can also be used, except that it would save the result in a `REG` file. The result of `REG.EXE` tool can also be redirected into a file with the help of `CMD.EXE`. For example:

```
CMD.EXE /C REG.EXE QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors" > "reg output.txt"
```

Note that the contents of the `output.txt` are different than the contents of `REG` file. The `REG` file has standard format which is partially described in Microsoft Knowledge Base [KB310516](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516).

By checking the exit code of `REG.EXE` tool, and parsing either its output or a generated `REG` file, retrieving registry value types are possible. Registry manipulations that can be done using `WScript.Shell` object should be used if possible and if performance is a concern.